# Nginx conf for Gunicorn on another vm?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I have hosted my Django project on Ubuntu using Gunicorn as a web server.

Now I want to serve my requests from Nginx but it should be on a different vm.

Normally my nginx **project.conf** would be like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

What changes should be made here to let Nginx route requests to my Gunicorn server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind Gunicorn to an IP address and port instead of a UNIX socket.

Then in your Nginx config, change `proxy_pass` to the IP address and port that you are running gunicorn on.

```
proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8000;
```